# Validate an input file in a directive(Angular.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I want to validate 2 fields of a form using a directive. The first field of text I want to be validated when I write the word "manuel". Then I want to validate that the input file is validated when loading an image. If the conditions are met, I set to true | false according to the validation.
If the validation of the text field is true then

```
 ngModel.$setValidity('validate', true);
```

otherwise

```
ngModel.$setValidity('validate', false);
```

(the same for the input file)

The problem is that the form is never valid, even if I load a valid image. What I can do?. I want to solve everything in a directive, if there is any better way to validate the input file, feedback is welcome, but do not want attributes as required and need this in the same directive.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal well" name="form" >
    <input type="text"  ng-model="numero"  class="form-control" validate />
    <input type="file" id='file' ng-model='file'  />
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" >SEND</button>
  </form>


    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
    });

    app.directive('validate', function ($timeout) {

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: 'ngModel', 

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
              if (!ngModel){
                return;          
              }
              //initially set false validation of form
              ngModel.$setValidity('validate', false);

              ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){
                if (val=="manuel"){
                  ngModel.$setValidity('validate', true);

                } else {
                  ngModel.$setValidity('validate', false);
                }
                ngModel.$render();
              })

                function bindEvent(element, type, handler) {
                  if (element.addEventListener) {
                    element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
                  } else {
                    element.attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
                  }
                }

                //******************** Validate File *********************//
                //initially set false validation of file
                ngModel.$setValidity('file', false);

                 bindEvent(element[0], 'change', function() {
                  var sNameFile=this.files[0].name;
                  var sExtension=sNameFile.split(".");
                  sExtension=sExtension[sExtension.length-1].toLowerCase();

                      if(sExtension=="gif" || sExtension=="jpg" || sExtension=="jpeg" || sExtension=="png" || sExtension=="bmp"){
                        console.log(" is image")
                         ngModel.$setValidity('file', true);
                         console.log(ngModel)
                      }
                      else{
                        console.log("is not image")
                        ngModel.$setValidity('file', false);
                        element[0].value=null;
                      }
                });

            }
        };
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/07u4muuq/

Comment: There is a problem in your jsfiddle `this.files` does not exists.

Comment: sorry! i updated the jsdfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/07u4muuq/

Comment: Use [jqLite element.on()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) to bind event listeners.

Comment: Also read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).